# How to apply after_stat with faceting in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, moving-average

I am using moving averages to smooth out the day-of-week effects in vaccine distribution, to see the general trends stratified by various factors. I can create a bar graph of rolling averages that displays the overall data correctly. But when I stratify or create facets, "ghost" bars of descending height appear in the lead-in period (which should have no bars). How can I avoid that?

#### correct graph (no stratification): g

[image]

#### graphs with "ghost" bars in moving average's lead-in period: g + facet_grid(race~., scales="free_y")

[image]

#### my code

```
library(tidyverse)
# Make fake data: count of doses per day for 70 days, increasing over the 70 days, with a 50% variance per day-of-week
nPerDay <- floor(sample(5:10, 70, replace=T) * (1 + ((1:70)*3/70)) * (.5 + (.5*(1:70 %% 7)/6)))
# Use that to create a data frame where one record is the administration of one dose, giving the dose, vaccine brand, 1st or 2nd dose, pt race, & pt gender
doses <- data.frame(Admin_date = rep(as.Date("2020-12-31") + 1:70, nPerDay)
                    , whichDose = factor(c(rep(1,sum(nPerDay[1:30])), sample(1:2, sum(nPerDay[31:70]), replace=T)))
                    , gender=sample(c("F", "M"), sum(nPerDay), replace=T)
                    , race=sample(LETTERS[1:5], sum(nPerDay), c(.45, .25, .15, .1, .05), replace=T)
                    , brand=sample(c("Pf", "Mo"), sum(nPerDay), replace=T)
)

# plot the doses administered each day, with stacked bars', with bars' color indicating # of 1st or second dose
(ggplot(data=doses, mapping=aes(x=Admin_date))#, fill=whichDose))
  + geom_bar(position = "stack")
  + geom_line(aes(y=..count.., fill=NULL), stat = "bin", binwidth=1)
)

# Change the bars in the prior plot into rolling 7-day averages, but keep the line as a daily total count.
g <- (
  ggplot(data=doses, mapping=aes(x=Admin_date))#, fill=whichDose)) 
  + geom_bar(position = "stack"
             , mapping = aes(y=zoo::rollmean(..count.., 7, align="right", fill=NA))
             , stat="bin", binwidth=1
  )
  + geom_line(aes(y=..count.., fill=NULL), stat = "bin", binwidth=1)
  + labs(y="doses", fill="Which dose,\n7d avg count")
)
g # display this base graph

# explore tha data
g + facet_grid(race~., scales="free_y") # See if the increasing trend and 1st vs 2nd dose porportions or similar across races.
```

I know that I can avoid this by creating an intermediate data frame that pre-computed the moving averages for the stratification I want. But there must be a way to do this on the fly in R, per https://yjunechoe.github.io/posts/2020-09-26-demystifying-stat-layers-ggplot2/ and maybe the [after_stat()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html) function. But I can't figure it out. My hope is to have a simple solution I can share with my work team, so the others (who have less R experience) can add facet functions to the base graph to explore the many factors we have - we have much more than gender, race, brand, and whichDose. If I can get rid of the ghost bars, they can just add code like this to get other stratifications:

```
# look at other stratifications
g + facet_grid(gender, scales="free_y")
g + facet_grid(race~brand, scales="free_y")
g + facet_grid(race~gender, scales="free_y")
```

Comment: I'd do it as an intermediate (much easier to see the data and work out what is wrong), then pipe that to the ggplot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after the stat is calculated, any calculation that happens after the stat doesn't necessarily take the panels into account. This gives problems with `zoo::rollmean`, because it just sees a single vector of values. Hence, you'd have to loop over the data by panel.

```r
library(tidyverse)

nPerDay <- floor(sample(5:10, 70, replace=T) * 
                   (1 + ((1:70)*3/70)) * (.5 + (.5*(1:70 %% 7)/6)))
doses <- data.frame(
  Admin_date = rep(as.Date("2020-12-31") + 1:70, nPerDay),
  whichDose = factor(c(rep(1,sum(nPerDay[1:30])), 
                       sample(1:2, sum(nPerDay[31:70]), replace=T))),
  gender=sample(c("F", "M"), sum(nPerDay), replace=T),
  race=sample(LETTERS[1:5], sum(nPerDay), c(.45, .25, .15, .1, .05), replace=T),
  brand=sample(c("Pf", "Mo"), sum(nPerDay), replace=T)
)


ggplot(data=doses[order(doses$race, doses$Admin_date), ], 
       mapping=aes(x=Admin_date)) +
  geom_bar(position = "identity"
           , mapping = aes(y=after_stat(
             unlist(lapply(split(count, PANEL), zoo::rollmean, 
                           7, align = "right", fill = NA))
           ))
           , stat="bin", binwidth=1
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y=..count.., fill=NULL), stat = "bin", binwidth=1) + 
  labs(y="doses", fill="Which dose,\n7d avg count") +
  facet_grid(race ~ ., scales = "free_y")
#> Warning: Removed 30 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand . My goal is to create a ggplot object "g" which has `fill=whichDose`, and to which I can add any facet variables I'd like. I removed `doses$race,` from `order(doses$race, doses$Admin_date)`, added `fill=whichDose` to the `ggplot(...aes())`, and changed `split(count, PANEL)` into `split(count, list(fill, PANEL)`. That worked well, but `... list(PANEL, fill)` did not - obviously, the order of PANEL vs fill matters. My questions: how do I figure out the correct order, except by trial and error? Where is the term PANEL documented, or this kind of use of count, fill, and PANEL?

Comment: The `PANEL` variable is a column that internally gets added to the data to well, divide up the data over panels. The way I've used this here is a bit of a hack. The proper way to do this is to [build a new stat](https://ggplot2-book.org/extensions.html#new-stats) that does the transformation without such hacks. The documented bits are in `?after_stat` and you'll find `count` in the `?stat_bin` 'computed variables' section.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the approach by @teunbrand (who deserves the credit for his concise explanation of the issue to which I have nothing to add) but making use of `dplyr` and a helper function you could achieve your desired result like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

# Make fake data: count of doses per day for 70 days, increasing over the 70 days, with a 50% variance per day-of-week
nPerDay <- floor(sample(5:10, 70, replace = T) * (1 + ((1:70) * 3 / 70)) * (.5 + (.5 * (1:70 %% 7) / 6)))
# Use that to create a data frame where one record is the administration of one dose, giving the dose, vaccine brand, 1st or 2nd dose, pt race, & pt gender
doses <- data.frame(
  Admin_date = rep(as.Date("2020-12-31") + 1:70, nPerDay),
  whichDose = factor(c(rep(1, sum(nPerDay[1:30])), sample(1:2, sum(nPerDay[31:70]), replace = T))),
  gender = sample(c("F", "M"), sum(nPerDay), replace = T),
  race = sample(LETTERS[1:5], sum(nPerDay), c(.45, .25, .15, .1, .05), replace = T),
  brand = sample(c("Pf", "Mo"), sum(nPerDay), replace = T)
)

my_rollmean <- function(count, group) {
  data.frame(group = group, count = count) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(roll = zoo::rollmean(count, 7, align = "right", fill = NA)) %>% 
    pull(roll)
}

# Change the bars in the prior plot into rolling 7-day averages, but keep the line as a daily total count.
g <- ggplot(data = doses, mapping = aes(x = Admin_date)) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "stack",
    mapping = aes(y = my_rollmean(..count.., ..PANEL..)),
    stat = "bin", binwidth = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = ..count.., fill = NULL), stat = "bin", binwidth = 1) +
  labs(y = "doses", fill = "Which dose,\n7d avg count")

# explore tha data
g + facet_grid(race ~ ., scales = "free_y") # See if the increasing trend and 1st vs 2nd dose porportions or similar across races.
#> Warning: Removed 30 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @stefan . Per my comment to @teunbrand, to stratify by fill, I added `fill=whichDose` to the `ggplot(aes())`, and changed `..PANEL..` to `interaction(fill, ..PANEL..)`. That worked well, and unlike with the @teunbrand's `lapply` approach, the (fill, PANEL) order did NOT seem to matter (`interaction(..PANEL.., fill)` produced the same results). Nice, but very confusing. I imagine that the reason is somewhere in [ggplot internals](https://ggplot2-book.org/internals.html#internals) .